# Git push old local commit to more current version of remote branch

Tags: git, version-control

I made a commit to my local repository that was not integrated into the remote repository. Now lots of work has been done on the remote repository, and when I do a "git pull", I have tons of staged changes now because they fail to merge automatically with my lone, local commit.

[image]

Is there a way to look at the most current revision on the remote branch and manually merge my commit into it? Reading about cherry-pick and rebase I cannot decide if they apply to my situation. I could do a fresh checkout of the project, and then copy/paste my code changes from one repo to another but I want to hear the correct way of doing it in case I have a larger commit in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, save your current work in another local branch not to loose it.

```
git checkout -b i-would-never-commit-to-develop-locally
```

Then, synchronize your local `develop` with the remote.

```
git fetch -f origin develop:develop
```

Rebase your branch to the `develop`.

```
git rebase develop
```

It is likely that you would have to resolve some conflicts here.

Finally, push your commit to the remote.

```
git push origin HEAD:remote-target-branch
```

Comment: Perfect set of instructions, and I now see the value of using a new branch (with a slightly different name than "i-would-never-commit-to-develop-locally") from now on.